# Keyboard binding for switching between Project Drawer and editor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I tried out Command+Option+` and Command+Option+~ but neither works on my machine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I generally use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in conjuction with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (reveal the file in drawer) to navigate my way around the folders.

Comment: Hmm, Ctrl+Tab for me edits the opened text file, and the cursor still stays in the editor. Thanks for the Ctrl+Command+R binding though!